# C# full list of status for PrintJob

Tags: c#, printing

I use WMI to get Printers and PrintJobs.
for each PrintJob, there's a property name "StatusMask". I'm trying to use this to monitor PrintJob's status.

I did a little test, found that when printing, it's 8272, when out of paper, it's 8274.

my question is, where I can get information of what these codes meaning? and how to use it?

I've already googled 'C# printjob statusmask', no valuable information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa394370(v=VS.85).aspx), it is the following:

> Bitmap of the possible statuses that relate to this print job.
>
> ```
> 1 (0x1)
> Paused
> 2 (0x2)
> Error
> 4 (0x4)
> Deleting
> 8 (0x8)
> Spooling
> 16 (0x10)
> Printing
> 32 (0x20)
> Offline
> 64 (0x40)
> Paperout
> 128 (0x80)
> Printed
> 256 (0x100)
> Deleted
> 512 (0x200)
> Blocked_DevQ
> 1024 (0x400)
> User_Intervention_Req
> 2048 (0x800)
> Restart
> ```